# Existing functional interface for one argument and return value (objects)

Tags: java, android, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to create a hash map of method references.
I can do that just fine by declaring my custom interface e.g.

```
private interface UICustom {  
    View create(MyObject element);    
}
```

and I can add my methods to the hashmap:
`hashmap.put("value", this::addField);`

I was thinking if I could avoid declaring my custom interface and perhaps there is something already available I could use instead.
So I found the `java.util.function.Function` but when I try to do `function.apply` I get the warning that the min required SDK is 24 but I can’t use that.
Is there a way to use some functional interface that already exists without declaring my own?

Answer (score 1):

[FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) are available from JDK 8. And it seems like JDK 8 can be used with SDK 24 onwards.

`::` operator is a method reference, and it is an example of Functional Interface type.